# The JavaScript drawing line doesn't fit on the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I draw on my canvas, the line doesn't follow the cursor, the line is at another point away from the cursor. for example, if I draw at point A, the cursor will stay at point A but the line I draw can be at point b.

I think this is happening because I want to make the canvas area (drawing area) larger, because if the canvas is the default size this won't happen

```js
const paintCanvas = document.querySelector('.js-paint');
const context = paintCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.lineCap = 'round';

const colorPicker = document.querySelector('.js-color-picker');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.js-clear-canvas');

clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, paintCanvas.width, paintCanvas.height);
});

colorPicker.addEventListener('change', event => {
    context.strokeStyle = event.target.value;
});

const lineWidthRange = document.querySelector('.js-line-range');
const lineWidthLabel = document.querySelector('.js-range-value');

lineWidthRange.addEventListener('input', event => {
    const width = event.target.value;
    lineWidthLabel.innerHTML = width;
    context.lineWidth = width;
});

let x = 0, y = 0;
let isMouseDown = false;

const stopDrawing = () => { isMouseDown = false; }
const startDrawing = event => {
    isMouseDown = true;
    [x, y] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
}
const drawLine = event => {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        const newX = event.offsetX;
        const newY = event.offsetY;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.lineTo(newX, newY);
        context.stroke();
        //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drawLine);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);
```

```css
.canvas {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 70vh;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 10px #208cff solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px inset grey, 0px 0px 15px #0263ca;
}

.canvas .paint-canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 70vh;
}

.canvas .paint-canvas:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.canvas .top {
    display: inline;
    
}
```

```html
<!-- Canvas -->
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Scratch Here</h1>
        <input type="color" class="js-color-picker color-picker">

        <div class="top">
            <input type="range" class="js-line-range" min="1" max="72" value="1">
            <label class="js-range-value">1</label>Px
        </div>

        <canvas class="js-paint  paint-canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
        <button class="js-clear-canvas">Clear Canvas</button>
    </div>
```